# jboss servlet startup dependancies

Tags: servlets, jboss, wildfly

I have a servlet supplied via packages jar (ServletA) that depends on the parameters loaded by ServletB from a database. The problem I have is that Jboss appears to spawn seperate threads for the initialization of the servlets. While in the logs I can see that the order defined by load-on-startup is correct, it appears the time taken by ServletB to read the database properties is causing ServletA to fail as its initialization kicks in and fails to get the properties since ServletB is still busy.

ServletA is a singleton and its initialization runs once and if it fails, there is no recovery. I do not have control over ServletA and as such cannot change this behavior.

Is there a setting in web.xml or for Jboss (wildfly) to define servlet startup dependacies? I am trying to get a way to make ServletA wait for the completion of ServletB's init() before its initialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a setting in web.xml or for Jboss (wildfly) to define servlet startup dependacies? I am trying to get a way to make ServletA wait for the completion of ServletB's init() before its initialization.

Yes, you can do that in the `web.xml` by using the parameter `load-on-startup`. It indicates an order for servlets to be loaded, servlets with higher numbers get loaded after servlets with lower numbers.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletA</servlet-name>
    <display-name>ServletA</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.stackoverflow.ServletA</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServletB</servlet-name>
    <display-name>ServletB</display-name>
    <servlet-class>com.stackoverflow.ServletB</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

However, as per the section 10.12 of the [servlet specs](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1484612672_fed7dc223089bfb51c0d667c013144c2), load-on-startup only determines the order of calling init() method on each servlet. It guarantees that the next servlet init will be called after the first servlet init is called. But it doesn't guarantee that the next init will be called after the *completion* of first init.

To achieve your goal, you can set a flag at the end of the init method of servletB and then wait in the init method of servletA for that flag to be set. E.g. write a 0 byte file in a temp folder at the end of the init method of the servletB and then in the init method of servletA wait for that file to be created.

Comment: I have load-on-startup similar to what you defined above. The order in which the servlets start up is correct. However though ServletB starts first, it takes some time reading the properties from the database. And while its still reading, ServletA starts initializing and fails.

Comment: @Phuthib, as per the section 10.12 of the [servlet specs](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1484612672_fed7dc223089bfb51c0d667c013144c2), load-on-startup only determines the order of calling init() method on each servlet. It guarantees that the next servlet init will be called after the first init is called. But it doesn't guarantee that the next init will be called after the completion of first init.

Comment: To achieve your goal, you can set a flag at the end of the init method of servletB and then wait in the init method of servletA for that flag to be set.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the solution was load-on-startup after all. My code was failing while still in ServletB.